# Identifying functional dependencies for a relation schema

Tags: database

I need to identify all non-trivial FDs for a relation - Students(sid, firstname, lastname, status, gpa, email) (email is unique).

So far I've found sid->firstname,lastname,status,gpa,email and 
email->sid,firstname,lastname,status,gpa

Have I missed any?(BTW i've been asked to use the union rule to combine as many FDs as possible.) Also remove any redundant FDs.

I'm checking one attribute with another and reasoning to find out if there's a non-trivial FD. Isn't there a more efficient way to go about this instead of comparing every attribute with every other attribute? Currently I'm just doing it manually by using real-world logic.

Ty.